# Foursquare API: Can you flag photo?

Tags: foursquare

Is there a way in the API to flag a photo as inappropriate.  We'd love to offer our users and our editors the ability to flag a photo and have it be reported back to Foursquare.  Even better if our editors find a photo, I'd love that to get higher weight in the 4sq review process.    But alas, I can't find any way in the docs (only flag a venue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot currently flag a photo via the API